# Can Voro++ be compiled in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, voronoi

I need to make Voronoi 3D diagram and I have chosen Voro++ to make this with Qt.

Can I compile voro++ in VS or should I use another library?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can. You need to:

1. Copy src folder in project folder and add these two file to project:

   - `src/voro++.hh`
   - `src/voro++.cc`
2. `#include "src/voro++.hh"`